# How do you use mouseleave in CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

It works with jQuery very well, but I want to remove jQuery and just use CSS transitions instead. I want a 3 second delay on mouseleave. How can I make this work with CSS?

```js
var hoverTimeout;
$('#theDiv').hover(function() {
  clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
  $(this).addClass('hovered');
}, function() {
  var $self = $(this);
  hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $self.removeClass('hovered');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.hovered {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="theDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider `transition-delay` **only** on the unhover state:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition:all 0s 3s;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: red;
  transition:all 0s;
}
```

```html
<div id="theDiv"></div>
```